# Transformation to make a curve

Tags: wpf, transformation

Is there a way to create a matrix transform or any other transformation to bend a rectangular element on the screen? Say I have a long rectangle: width=50 and height = 500. And 2/3 of the way down I want it to turn 90 degrees.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are the various Geometry classes, especially PathGeometry.
These links are a good start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using now to build all my curves, but it makes some of the other application logic complicated. So, I was wondering if there is a simple solution to make something bend using matrix transform or something like that.

Comment: Not that I know of.  All of the available transforms appear to be linear/affine.

Comment: This would not be that hard with a path as it just 6 straight lines.

Comment: Marking this as an answer. I ended up using geometries to achieve what I wanted to do, just needed to spend more time on coming up with a solution that would work for my users. While using pixel shaders could've worked, this works better for what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pixel shader (effect in WPF), however this will render the hit test in that area useless.

Comment: That would be a cool thing to try, but I do need the area to remain hit testable.